# Function type has ambiguous reference to member nextInt()

Tags: swift, ambiguous

My intent is to use `nextInt(upperBound: Int)`

```
let randomInt: (Int) -> Int = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt
var myNumber = randomInt(10)
```

Produce error: *Playground execution failed: error: ambiguous reference to member 'nextInt()'*

Why?

Swift 3, xCode 8 beta 6

Comment: Compiles fine for me – maybe try cleaning your build folder? You could also try disambiguating by referring to the method as `GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound:)`

Comment: I'm playing with Playground. This error popped up in Debug area on bottom.

Comment: Playgrounds are notoriously buggy – try in a full project

Comment: It compiles and works for me in an Xcode 8 beta 6 Playground. Do you import something else than GameKit?

Comment: @EricAya UIKit and GameplayKit

Comment: Can't reproduce any error. Voting to close.

Comment: Huh... I *can* reproduce your problem in an Xcode 8 beta 6 playground – and for some reason changing the method type to `(UInt) -> UInt` allows it to compile and run (although Xcode still generates an inline error). You should probably file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: @Hamish you have me there. But I still can't reproduce in an app.

Comment: @matt I also cannot reproduce it in a full project (I assume that's what you mean by "in an app"), but in a playground ([my exact playground](https://infinit.io/_/jg8perb)), the console will generate an error of "*ambiguous reference to member 'nextInt()'*" (although no inline errors will be generated). The two candidates the compiler find are `open func nextInt() -> Int` & `open func nextInt(upperBound: UInt) -> UInt` (I have no idea where the `UInt` comes from). Something weird is definitely going on here – I certainly agree with you that playgrounds are the work of the devil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code compiles fine in a real iOS app, as shown by this screen shot:

[image]

That, an actual iOS app project, is the real test of whether code is valid. Playgrounds do *not* represent real Swift environments.

Comment: Actually, I regard playgrounds as the work of the devil and I wish they had never been invented. But that's another story. (Actually, it's the same story.)